# Intersection of images and union of kernels.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a ring (not necessarily commutative), let $M$ be an $A$-module, and let $u: M \to M$ be an $A$-module morphism. Put $$\text{Image}(u^\infty) := \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \text{Image}(u^k),\text{ resp. }\text{Ker}(u^\infty) = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \text{Ker}(u^k).$$Are $\text{Image}(u^\infty)$ and $\text{Ker}(u^\infty)$ necessarily $A$-submodules in $M$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection of any family of submodules is a submodule. For the kernels, it is true because the different $\ker u^k$  are linearly ordered (actually, it is a direct limit), hence if you take $x\in\ker u^k$, $y\in\ker u^l$ for some $k,l$, one of them in contained in the other, say $\ker u^k\subseteq\ker u^l$, hence $x+y$ exists in $\ker u^l$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use the following facts to prove it:

1. kernels and images are submodules
2. intersection of submodules are submodules. So $\operatorname{Im}(u^{\infty})$ is a submodule
3. If $C$ is a chain of submodules, then $\bigcup C$ is a submodule. Since $\ker(u^n) \subset \ker (u^{n+1})$ for all $n$, $\ker (u^{\infty})$ is a submodule.