# Followup to my previous question, $M = \text{Image}(u^\infty) \oplus \text{Ker}(u^\infty)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, multilinear-algebra

See my previous question here, [Intersection of images and union of kernels.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396830/intersection-of-images-and-union-of-kernels)

> Let $A$ be a ring (not necessarily commutative), let $M$ be an $A$-module, and let $u: M \to M$ be an $A$-module morphism. Put $$\text{Image}(u^\infty) := \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \text{Image}(u^k),\text{ resp. }\text{Ker}(u^\infty) = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \text{Ker}(u^k).$$Are $\text{Image}(u^\infty)$ and $\text{Ker}(u^\infty)$ necessarily $A$-submodules in $M$?

My question this time around is, do we moreover have that$$M = \text{Image}(u^\infty) \oplus \text{Ker}(u^\infty)?$$

Comment: Not true. $A$ could be a field of characteristic $0$; $M$ could be the polynomial ring over $A$; $u$ could be the operator of differentiation. Both the image and the kernel are the whole $M$ in this case. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitting_lemma for a sufficient condition for your queston to have an affirmative answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since we have$$M \supseteq \text{Im}(u) \supseteq \text{Im}(u^2) \supseteq \dots$$and $M$ is of finite length, we must have some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  for all $k' \ge k$,$$\text{Im}(u^{k'}) = \text{Im}(u^k) = \text{Im}(u^\infty).$$Since we also have$$\text{Ker}(u) \subseteq \text{Ker}(u^2) \subseteq \dots \subseteq M,$$we get that for all $k' \ge k$,$$\text{Ker}(u^{k'}) = \text{Ker}(u^k) = \text{Ker}(u^\infty).$$

- **Proof that $M = \text{Ker}(u^\infty) \oplus \text{Im}(u^\infty)$.** Assume $a \in M$, and let $a_1 = u^k(a) \in \text{Im}(u^\infty)$. So$$u^k(a - a_1) = a_1 - u^k(a_1) = a- u^{2k}(a).$$Since $a_1 \in \text{Im}(u^\infty)$, there is $a_2 \in M$ such that $a = u^{2k}(a_2)$. Hence,$$u^k(a - a_1 - u^k(a_2 - a)) = u^k(a - u^k(a_2)) = 0.$$So$$b_1 = a- u^k(a_2) \in \text{Ker}(u^k) = \text{Ker}(u^\infty),\text{ }b_2 = u^k(a_2) \in \text{Im}(u^k) = \text{Im}(u^\infty).$$Thus,$$a = b_1 \oplus b_2 \in \text{Ker}(u^\infty) \oplus \text{Im}(u^\infty),$$and so$$M = \text{Ker}(u^\infty) \oplus \text{Im}(u^\infty).$$
- **Proof that $\text{Ker}(u^\infty) \cap \text{Im}(u^\infty) = \{0\}$.** Assume that $\lambda \in \text{Ker}(u^\infty) \cap \text{Im}(u^\infty)$. So $u^k(\lambda) = 0$, and there is $\lambda_1 \in M$ such that $\lambda = u^k(\lambda_1)$. Therefore, $$u^{2k}(\lambda_1) = 0 \text{ and }\lambda_1 \in \text{Ker}(u^{2k}) = \text{Ker}(u^\infty) = \text{Ker}(u^k).$$So $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: Where is it said that $M$ is of finite length?

Comment: This is the sufficient condition @darij grinberg mentions in his comment.